# cmd parse json file

Tags: json, cmd, for

Есть файл **count.json**.

Вот его содержимое:

> {"total":34265,"entries":[...]

Как получить **34265**? Начало файла **{"total":** всегда одно, но значение после может быть разным.
Есть ли способ получить строку с первого **двоеточия** по первую **запятую**? Понимаю, что нужно через `for`, но как точно не получается.

Comment: А `jq` вообще нельзя использовать?

Comment: @donRumata, лишь стандартный набор cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:," %%x IN (count.json) DO echo %%x
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: При запуске данного кода через `cmd` двойной знак `%` не нужен, насколько я понимаю. Если я не ошибаюсь, вы написали пример для bat-файла?

Comment: @VenZell Ну да, товарищ просил код именно для батча, а не для командной строки.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Вот я, признаться, даже представить не могу, что тут вообще может требовать развёртывания.

Comment: я весьма далёк от ms/windows вообще и используемой там оболчки в частности. но из общих соображений могу предположить, что не помешала бы расшифровка, каким именно образом предложенный вами код позволяет «получить строку с первого двоеточия по первую запятую». // ну а вообще в подобных нашей дискуссиях я как правило упоминаю «уловку 22». в приложении к нашему сайту она бы прозвучала примерно так: «у того, кому не нужна расшифровка приведённого куска кода, скорее всего, данный вопрос вообще не возникнет: он ведь и сам сможет этот кусок написать».

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, чуть другим способом решил до Вашего ответа. Они схожи, только у меня в 2 действия. 1 - обрезаю после **запятой**, 2 - беру после **{"total":**. Ваш способ проще, исправлю на него в дальнейшем